# Accessing $rootScope methods in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

In [this ng-book JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UWuLALOf/1/edit), does `$scope.$watch()` resolves to `$rootScope.$watch()` due to prototypal inheritance.

Can we inject `$rootScope` explicitly inside the controller so that `$scope` would be same as `$rootScope` inside the controller, without going through prototypal inheritance?

Replicating code here for reference:

```
    // open this example and type person.name into the test field
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController',
    ['$scope', '$parse', function($scope, $parse) {

      $scope.person = {
        name: "Ari Lerner"
      };

      $scope.$watch('expr', function(newVal, oldVal, scope) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          // Let's set up our parseFun with the expression
          var parseFun = $parse(newVal);
          // Get the value of the parsed expression, set it on the scope for output
          scope.parsedExpr = parseFun(scope);
        }
      });
    }]);
```

Comment: sure it can be injected, it will not be `same as $scope` though, `$scope` will still be a child of root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inject it the same way as `$scope` or `$parse`, anything defined on $rootScope will be then accessible inside your controller.

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$parse', '$rootScope', 
   function($scope, $parse, $rootScope) {

      $rootScope.foo();

      console.log($rootScope.bar);
   }
]);
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the `rootScope` so badly, it has a provider just as `scope` does. Including `'$rootScope'` into your controller as you do with the `'$scope'` does the trick.

There's also the `$parent` attribute of the `$scope` which could come in handy, but IMO it tends to make code less maintainable if abused. In particular when multiple scopes are nested, as you need to traverse the whole hierarchy.